# Is there any way, even a hacky one, to disable / hide / remove the "Clock" on the macOS Monterey menu-bar?

Tags: menu-bar, monterey, clock

I use iStat Menus to get a far-superior "fuzzy clock" in my menubar.

Unfortunately, Monterey seems to have removed the option I depended on that completely removed the built-in macOS menubar-clock; and now I have two:

[image: a screenshot of the macOS menubar, with both a fuzzy clock saying 'quarter past eleven' and a circular analog clock visible beside eachother]

I'm open to hacky solutions. Anybody got something? I hate the clutter.

Comment: Can't test Monterey. Hold Cmd, drag the icon down out of the menu bar into empty desktop space & let go

Comment: Command clock doesn’t change the clock since that space also serves as do not disturb toggle (option select) and brings up the [Notifications Center](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079).